# homebrew installation working, but brew not working OSX 10.8.5

Tags: installation, osx-mountain-lion, homebrew

I know that this isn't something that I do on a daily basis. However, this is really weird. I installed Homebrew using : `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"`

The I actually got this response:

"

```
> ==> This script will install: /usr/local/bin/brew /usr/local/Library/... /usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1
> 
> Press ENTER to continue or any other key to abort
> ==> Downloading and Installing Homebrew... remote: Finding bitmap roots... remote: Counting objects: 132404, done. remote: Compressing
> objects: 100% (43037/43037), done. remote: Total 132404 (delta 91508),
> reused 129108 (delta 88342) Receiving objects: 100% (132404/132404),
> 31.72 MiB | 2.51 MiB/s, done. Resolving deltas: 100% (91508/91508), done. From https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew  * [new branch]     
> master     -> origin/master HEAD is now at 27cc45c rhash 1.3.0
> Warning: /usr/local/bin is not in your PATH.
> ==> Installation successful! You should run `brew doctor' *before* you install anything. Now type: brew help
```

"

You will actually think that this installs it. But then I do `brew doctor` and this is the response:

brew help
-bash: brew: command not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to your shell configuration file (i.e. ~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc):

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH
```

Start a new terminal session and things should be fine.